# How to use inherid remote methods on Angular SDK

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I have a model with BaseModel with a relations type hasMany to Image model and I have a model that extend that model e.g. Person. in the client side I can do

In some part of my code I do

```
Person.findOne({id: ...})
  .$promise
  .then(function(instance){...})
```

In another part I do

```
Person.images({id: instance.id})
  .$promise
  .then(function(images) {...})
```

Now I have two another model than extend from BaseModel (Worker) So i can't use `Person.images` anymore in the second part because if the instance is a Worker the URL will be wrong and will find a 404 error

How I can create images using the instance, Instead `Person.images` use `instance.images`

Comment: You need to create a service for each instance and call that instance's service as runtime. You can have a generic `instance.images()` but you will need to create check the instance type during runtime and then proceed to call the relevant instance's service.

Comment: @callmekatootie I dont understand well, could you please add a answer with some example code